# Windows 10: Upload speed drops after startup

Tags: networking, windows-10

I've noticed that I have some trouble lately with my upload.
What I notice is that the second windows starts, and I do a speedtest, I reach about 50 mb/s down and 5 up.

Every other device, wifi or cable does reach about the same. (Wifi a bit lower.)

However, if I wait ± 3 minutes or so, and do another one, i get roughly 48mbs down and 0.30mbs up.

It stays about 0.0mbs up for 80% of the time, and jumps to 0.3 in the last few seconds..

Now what I've tried:

- Other cable
- Direct connection to modem (normally there's a router inbetween)
- BIOS Update
- BIOS Flash
- Attempt to remove any malicious software
- Check startup software (None that are really high demanding)
- Added network card to motherboard, as I suspected that to be the problem
- Changed RAM
- Removed couple of HDD's

I had the idea that my computer might be having issues ' processing ' .. 'it' ..?

- List item Uninstalled any software I can live without
- No updates are running, no downloads, no other devices using network

Specs:
Sabertooth Z77
4x4GB DDR 1300
Cat 5 
Windows 10 64b on 128GB OCZ Agi3 SSD

Any idea's why my upload would be at 'full' power when JUST started, but literally dies after a few minutes?

Comment: What’s not clear is if this problem is affecting only one machine or multiple machines?

Comment: @Appleoddity Just one

Comment: What speed do you get on other devices after the affected machine starts acting up?

Comment: @Appleoddity 50/5

Comment: are you able to observe your networks usage from another machine, like your router? Is it possible that your ISP is downgrading your connection for reasons like data caps, peak time management, supposed illicit traffic, etc? its likely that ISP responses to events like you coming online might take a few seconds to kick in. from another angle, you have done a lot already. about the only malware that could hide traffic entirely would be a rootkit. have you tried a fresh install of the OS? also, have you tried temporarily disabling your Antivirus/firewall?  no proxies or VPN, right?

Comment: Hi @FrankThomas, I doubt that it's my ISP. I ran multiple tests during the day where as my phone (and every other device) reaches higher upload than my PC.
I've tried to run without firewall/antivirus / realtime protection etc. No proxies nor VPN either. Cable is working fine as well, as other machines connected to the *same* cable do get the (correct) down/up.

What I noticed is that, when I just started windows and go to speedtest.net immidiately to test it, I do reach the 50/5 that I expect, but after a minute or two, it becomes a 50/0.5-1. Very confused.. :(